# Unable to import Material UI Labs into React app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to use Material Ui Lab's checkboxes [link](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes). But after npm installing the three dependencies: `@material-ui/lab`, `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/icons`, I am receiving this error:

`./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Portal/Portal.js Attempted import error: 'HTMLElementType' is not exported from '@material-ui/utils'.`

My imports are as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';
```

And the two dependency versions are:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56"
```

I have tried deleting node modules and npm installing again to no avail, I've also tried to install `@material-ui/utils`.

Comment: I don't know what's the issue but I tried doing it in codesandox and everything works fine : https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-leaf-gefwy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-lake-85e3y?file=/src/App.js) using the example [from the docs](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#checkboxes).  Compare your solution to that.  If you are still unsure why it isn't working, we're going to need to see more code/config.

Comment: Yeah even I could do that just now

Comment: i am install package `@material-ui/core` `@material-ui/icons` `@material-ui/lab`.It is also possible that there is a script overlap that will be resolved by executing the `yarn` or `npm` command.

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem by updating the react, react-dom & react-scripts packages to the versions found in your example, thank you!